# How to create change image option on mousehover like in gmail account?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create change image functionality like we can do in GMail account for changing our image.

On `mousehover` event it shows `change image` option.

Maybe it is some kind of new concept that I don't know. I am not very good in CSS and JavaScript but I guess that it is a `div` with changed `z-index` showing `change image` option.
Could you please explain how to achieve that kind of effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version using the css pseudo-element `:after`:

#### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zNs56/1/)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c0b4455b645967c1431d73beea9d9c54?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.image img{
    width: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.image:after{
    content: "Change Image";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(77, 144, 254, 0.7);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}
.image:hover:after{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure CSS solution than you can try it like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jvCh4/)

```
div.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.wrap img {
    position: absolute;
}

div.wrap img:nth-of-type(1) {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 3s;
}

div.wrap:hover img:nth-of-type(1) {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
}

div.wrap img:nth-of-type(2) {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 3s;
}

div.wrap:hover img:nth-of-type(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: but in this demo full image getting changed.

Comment: @user460293 So what you want to change?

Comment: i want to show link to change image on mousehover like in gmail.

Comment: @user460293 I got it, check out CSS sprites, just google that

Comment: What do you know about PURE CSS? :D

Comment: @moredemons I know too much :D

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean?

CSS

```
.image {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
.popup {
    top: -25px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    background-color: grey;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.image:hover + .popup {
    display: block;
}
.popup:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<img class="image" src="http://img83.imageshack.us/img83/1905/dsc005142kc.jpg" />
<div class="popup"><a href="#">Change Image</a></div>
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/KrDLA/)

Comment: I did, and this example is very similar to what I see on my gmail account. In fact it is very similar to the answer that you accepted, so I don't know what you are trying to emphasize. What I do know is; your question was not very clear.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand what you want but I'd say something like that :

HTML :

```
<img src="yourimage" />
<a href="changeYourImage" class="appearOnHover">change</a>
```

CSS :

```
a.appearOnHover {
    display: none;
}

a.appearOnHover {
    display: block;
    background-color: #777777;
}
```